# Are there formulae for calculating stellar luminosity and effective temperature as a function of age?

Tags: astrophysics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there formulae for calculating stellar luminosity and effective temperature as a function of age?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/are-there-formulae-for-calculating-stellar-luminosity-and-effective-temperature)

Is there a manageable formula or set of formulas or simple algorithms that approximate stellar luminosity and effective temperature (or radius) as a function of stellar age?

I'm aware that accurate modeling of these attributes is complex and is determined by many factors; what I'm looking for is something that serves as a decent approximation of the sort used in numerous illustrations or applets that show example "paths" taken by representative stars as they trace their evolution across the H-R diagram.

(From [this original question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/are-there-formulae-for-calculating-stellar-luminosity-and-effective-temperature-a) posted on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).)